# MongoDB: Missing fields after sort() when using projection

Tags: mongodb

So I have a database filled with image information, and I want to retrieve a subset of the fields sorted by ascending date. I use the following query to retrieve the aggregated set:

```
db.images.find({}, {rel_path: 1, date: 1}).sort({'date.year': 1, 'date.month': 1})
```

I expect this query to return a set looking something like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("530deb1060832c64291a11a7"), 
    "date": { "year: 2006, "month": 2 },
    "rel_path": "/mnt/backup/Backup/Photos/asdfasdfasdf.jpg"
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("530de1db60832c64291a05ec"), 
    "date": { "year: 2006, "month": 5 },
    "rel_path": "/mnt/backup/Backup/Photos/qweqweqwe.jpg"
}
... <more documents> ...
```

What I get, however, looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("530deb1060832c64291a11a7"), 
    "rel_path": "/mnt/backup/Backup/Photos/asdfasdfasdf.jpg"
}
{
    "_id": ObjectId("530de1db60832c64291a05ec"), 
    "rel_path": "/mnt/backup/Backup/Photos/qweqweqwe.jpg"
}
... <more documents> ...
```

If I skip the 'sort()' I get all fields from my projection, so it seems the 'date' field somehow is removed by the 'sort()' call.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

**Edit:** Here's a sample document by request:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("530de16860832c64291a0562"), 
    "orientation" : 1, 
    "camera_make" : "Apple", 
    "camera_model" : "iPhone 4", 
    "rel_path" : "Bröllopsbilder/IMG_0997.JPG", 
    "file_size" : 1827977, 
    "date" : { "month" : "10", "year" : "2011" }, 
    "root" : "/mnt/backup/Backup/Bilder/", 
    "md5" : "fb26ebf24914d515144be5e53797744b" 
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample document from the collection?

Comment: I've added a sample to the post.

Comment: Are you using the same find() query you posted above or a different one?  I'm asking this because you mention "aggregate set" and the output you posted looks like the result of an aggregation query (since it's an array), but you've posted a find() query, which seems correct and should return the year and month as expected.

Comment: Sorry that's my bad, I was writing it out of memory from doing it in mongojs, but I'll update the post to reflect the actual output.

Comment: The query seems fine and it works as expected.  I tested it by running it against a similar data set.  Do all documents in the collection have the "date" field?

Comment: Oh wait! I just found the "problem". For some documents (specifically where the exif parsing failed) are missing the 'date' field. I thought those would be omitted but I guess they are included and sorted on top. So the reason the 'date' field is missing is just because it really isn't there :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment. Feel free to write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Honestly I don't see any valid answer, it's worthless and it doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The find() query looks fine and it works as expected. I tested it by running it against a similar data set.

Reason this could be happening is when a few documents in the collection do **not** have the "date" field.  Try running the same query by adding a filter criteria in the find query to return only those results where "date" field exists using [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator i.e.,:

```
db.images.find({date:{$exists:true}}, {rel_path: 1, date: 1})
         .sort({'date.year': 1, 'date.month': 1})
```